# What's best way for create and save 'alias' commands by user?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, alias

I need create differences alias by user in the same OS, execute this when initialize user session and open the terminal ('alias' the other sessions should not run).

Example:

User #1:

```
alias topen="open -a TextEdit"
alias tree="ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e  's/^//' -e 's/-/|/'"
```

User #2:

```
alias textopen="open -a TextEdit"
```

- (this don't have tree 'alias')

User #3:

- It's default and don't have alias.

How to solve this problem in terminal? I'll be very grateful.

Comment: I don't understand the problem you're trying to solve. You want all your users to have some aliases in common? If so, you can create a file in /etc/profile.d with a ".sh" extension that contains them. bash will eventually source all the files in that directory.

However, what if your users don't use bash as their login shell?

Answer (score 0):

When you login as a certain user, the file `.profile` is executed. By adding the mentioned commands to that file, you can get those commands executed.

In case you want to know where to find those `.profile` files, just check `/etc/passwd` file.

Comment: `/etc/passwd` contains only the home directory and the default shell as paths. `~/.bashrc` file can be simply used without any special user privileges.